# JavaScript - Console-like output for API calls

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement something that looks like a console window, but on a webpage. I'd like it to just write a new line pinging an API every second or so. I have:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  text = httpGet('APICALL' );
  document.write(text + '<br>');
  sleep(1000);
}
```

This however, runs ALL the calls first and then writes. How can I change this?

EDIT:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. Read what it does. Try innerHTML of an element.

Comment: What is `sleep`?

Comment: @tymeJV I added that.

Comment: Javascript is single threaded. You shouldn't make a sleep function like this because it will hang up the main thread and make the user unable to do anything until it's finished running. Right now you only make a request five times so control is eventually given back to the user, but if you want this to constantly run "in the background", so to speak, use setTimeout or setInterval. Otherwise it's about the same as writing an infinite loop.

Comment: This is the only function of the site right now, so no issue there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like setTimeout, which is a [standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) way of doing it:

```
var sleepTime = 1000;
var i = 0;

setTimeout(function readNextMessage() {
  if (i < 5) {
    text = httpGet('https://turbine-farm.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/api/turbines/1/heartbeat' );
    document.body.innerHTML += text + '<br>';
  }
  i += 1;
  setTimeout(readNextMessage, sleepTime);
}, sleepTime);
```

You **cant** *sleep* a webpage. Your `sleep` function is doing this:

1. Enters into a loop of `1e7` steps.
2. Each step does a difference and compares it to a number.
3. It breaks if comparison is true.

Those 3 steeps, in a modern computer, are done in less than a second.

Comment: The sleep is not the issue - I can make the function sleep, but write doesn't write the line right away, it waits for the whole loop to finish.

Comment: I changed document.write to document.body.innerHTML. Is it working now?

Comment: The issue is that the write function doesn't write right away to the webpage. I can see a blank screen for 5 seconds, then 5 lines written. I want 1 second - one line - 2 second - 2 lines etc.

Comment: I've also fixed a bug. I forgot to recursively call setTimeout.

Comment: @ite__ You should definitely use setTimeout instead of the inefficient `sleep()` function you posted above.